# Trapezaoidal rule for oscillating integrand

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

If integral which contains an oscillating function, e.g. a Bessel function, is solved with a trapezoidal rule I am getting that the answer of the integral is fluctuating about value when I increase the sample size and continuously increasing the sample size increasingly converges the answer to this value. Is this behavior reasonable for a fluctuating function as the integrand?

Here is a picture to make the question a bit clear (please ignore the CLASS curve in the figure below)
[image]

Comment: Could you be more explicit about the parameters of the integration? The first order error term can be written as $-\frac{h^2}{12}(f'(b)-f'(a))$, there should only be oscillations while the other higher order terms dominate the error, that is, for larger values of $h$.

Comment: So, in the particular experience, I am speaking of, the trapezoidal rule was applied iteratively between points to evaluate the integral. The value of h between the points was increasingly small. Is that what you wanted to know?

Comment: What Bessel function, what interval, is that interval fixed for all computations in question? Is the integration with a fixed step size or with an adaptive-grid algorithm?

Comment: Spherical Bessel function (particularly for ell greater than 50), the interval between points is logarithmic (short close to zero, large for large values) but constant (not adaptive)

Comment: To add a bit more information, the resultant function is a plot against the value of ell and the tail of the function at large ell "oscillates" about a certain curve but as h is reduced by increasing the number of intervals, it settles smaller oscillations.

Comment: Reducing the step increases accuracy, this is quite normal. Anyway, at a certain point, numerical errors will start accumulating and accuracy degrades. But I see nothing abnormal on your plots, so what is the question ?

Comment: The blue dashed curve for 800 samples of z, increasing the samples causes the tail of the curve to "oscillate" about the blue dashed curve. However, increasing the samples further settles it close to the dashed blue curve (notice the light blue dotted curves). So, my question is the oscillations if they are normal. I am trying to ascertain stability of the numerical recipes. I have seen in my experience that the difference between curves reduces as the number of samples increases but the "oscillations" are rather new to me. I was curious about the oscillations, really.